# android mapview with custom wms tile provider

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid, wms

i want to load my wms server to show tiles from there. i used carto/nutiteq and everything is ok but i want it open source or free license . then i try osmdroid library but i can't implement my wms can anyone help me ?

```
// Web Mercator n/w corner of the map.
private static final double[] TILE_ORIGIN = {-20037508.34789244, 20037508.34789244};
//array indexes for that data
private static final int ORIG_X = 0;
private static final int ORIG_Y = 1; //
private static String mLayername = "";

// Size of square world map in meters, using WebMerc projection.
private static final double MAP_SIZE = 20037508.34789244 * 2;

// array indexes for array to hold bounding boxes.
protected static final int MINX = 0;
protected static final int MAXX = 1;
protected static final int MINY = 2;
protected static final int MAXY = 3;
private String layer = "";

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param aName    a human-friendly name for this tile source
 * @param aBaseUrl the base url(s) of the tile server used when constructing the url to download the tiles http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/geoserver/wms
 */
public WMSTileProvider(String aName, String[] aBaseUrl, String layername) {
    super(aName, 8, 22, 255, "image/png", aBaseUrl);
    mLayername = layername;
}


final String WMS_FORMAT_STRING =
        "http://dev.shiveh.com/shiveh?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=Shiveh%3AShivehGSLD256&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=false&version=1.1.1&height=256&width=256&srs=EPSG%3A4326&bbox=";
protected double[] getBoundingBox(int x, int y, int zoom) {
    double tileSize = MAP_SIZE / Math.pow(2, zoom);
    double minx = TILE_ORIGIN[ORIG_X] + x * tileSize;
    double maxx = TILE_ORIGIN[ORIG_X] + (x + 1) * tileSize;
    double miny = TILE_ORIGIN[ORIG_Y] - (y + 1) * tileSize;
    double maxy = TILE_ORIGIN[ORIG_Y] - y * tileSize;

    double[] bbox = new double[4];
    bbox[MINX] = minx;
    bbox[MINY] = miny;
    bbox[MAXX] = maxx;
    bbox[MAXY] = maxy;

    return bbox;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinate reference system in your url EPSG:4326 which is lat/lon wgs84.  However the equations you have appear to look like the equations to convert from slippy map coordinates to EPSG:900913.

Does your server support that CRS? Try switching the CRS url parameter to EPSG:900913 or change the equation to compute the coordinates for the requested tile